# I am simply trying to round to the nearest whole number with my existing data. I keep getting an error returned when I try the round function

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I am sorting video game information using pandas. I have the data I need and all I needed is the result to round to the nearest whole number..

```
# Create a data frame with the properly queried and sorted data
semi1 = (ratingSort.sort_values(by=['numVotes', 'averageRating'], ascending=False))

# Create a data frame with only the required columns
semi2 = semi1[['primaryTitle', 'startYear', 'averageRating', 'numVotes']]

# Create a data frame with a subset of records
final = (semi2.head(10))

final
```

(Data Printed correctly here)

then I tried this to round to the nearest whole number:

```
['User_Count'].round(decimals=0)
```

This returns and error. I also tried:

```
final = ['User_Count'].round(decimals=0)
```

The column titles are 'User_Count' and 'Name'

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[66], line 1
----> 1 final = ['User_Count'].round(decimals=0)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'round'

Comment: `['User_Count']` is just a list.  I think you meant to put the dataframe `final['User_Count']`

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening because you are calling round on a list that just contains the word 'User_Count'. When you write ['User_Count'] python will create a list with one element, and that element will be the string 'User_Count'.  What you need to do is call the round function on a pandas dataframe.

First, add the 'User_Count' column to your final dataframe:

```
semi2 = semi1[['primaryTitle', 'startYear', 'averageRating', 'numVotes', 'User_Count']]
final = semi2.head(10)
```

Next, call the round function on the 'User_Count' column in the resulting dataframe

```
final['User_Count'].round(decimals=0)
```

For some more information, here is the documentation on the pandas.DataFrame.round function: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused due to this line:

`['User_Count'].round(decimals=0)`

As youre using sqaure brackets around 'User_Count', python is creating a list with the element 'User_Count' as a string and attempting to call round using it. Since, the list doesnt have a method called round, this error is being raised.